# Setting dynamic placeholder text in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, dynamic, placeholder

I'm fairly new to rails.  I'm building an app that has 5 templates for 5 forms.  I don't really need to build 5 forms, just somehow replace the placeholder text depending on the template.  What is the best way to do this?  A helper file?  What would the process be called so I can look it up?

Answer (score 0):

put the text you need into an `@instance_variable` inside your controller and then you'll have access to that in your view templates.

Then, do some business logic on the backend to determine what text that variable will hold.

Comment: There are about 20 different input fields...this seems like it would really crowd my controller to put 20 different sentences.  Do you have any advice?

Comment: I would create a class with a method that determines the text.  Pass the context to the method in the controller and it will return the text you need.

Kinda hard to give you the solution I would choose without a lot more information.